# Is this a valid use of Akka?

Tags: java, akka

I have 4 web services which need to be invoked in order  :

```
w1
w2
w3
w4
```

So for each user 4 web services are invoked.

I'm wrapping these services within an Akka solution so that each service is called one after the other.
Should each of these calls be hands within

1. A single Akka actor?
2. An Akka thread be created for each individual service ?

w4 returns details to user. So if 10 users request details using option 1, 10 actors are created, using option 2, 40 actors are created.

Any pointers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you need to maintain a state. If all you want to call these four services in some sequence and you can use some async IO library (like [Spray client](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-client/)), you can probably get away with using a single actor and for comprehension on Futures with no blocking, something like this:

```
def callW1() : Future[W1Response] = ???

...

def receive : Receive = {
case m : SomeMessage => {
  val response : Future[YourResponse] = for {
    w1Response <- callW1();
    w2Response <- callW2(w2Response);
    w3Response <- callW3(w2Response, w3Response);
    w4Response <- callW4();
  } yield w4Response

 val savedSender = sender()

 response.foreach(savedSender ! _)
 }
}
```

The number of threads processing messages and futures can be configured via .config file (20 by default).

On the other hand if you want to, say, cache webservice responses, you'd better create a wrapper actor for each webservice with caching logic and also a supervisor actor that manages the sequence of their calls.

Here is some more reading on this topic : [Actors vs Futures](http://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/actors_vs_futures.html)